# Sum values of checkbox labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've got checkboxes with labels like `1 some text` I would like to get the number out of the labels of the checkboxes that are checked and add them together. I was trying to do something like what I have below but it is not giving me anything.

```
var total = 0;

$('input:checked').each(function () {
    total += parseInt($("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text());
});
```

Here is an example checkbox

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="enbapicks-1" name="ENBApicks[1]" value="1" checked> 1 Golden State</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="enbapicks-5" name="ENBApicks[5]" value="1" checked> 5 Memphis</label>
```

Comment: What is the value of `str` after you have assigned it?  Not your assumed value - the *actual* value?

Comment: Some notes on `parseInt`: if your string BEGINS with the number you are trying to extract, you don't need to `substr`.  `parseInt` will return whatever number it finds until it reaches a non-numerical character.  `parseInt("12potato");` will return `12`.  Also, its best practice to always specify a `radix` even if you don't think you need to: `parseInt(str, 10);`

Comment: the value seems to be empty

Comment: Why don't you get the text of each checkbox with `.val()`?

Comment: @BzH OP is looking for the text value of each checkbox's associated `label` element, not the checkbox value itself.

Comment: @MichaelStClair There's your problem.  Have a look at your `this.id` value, and the result of `$("label[for='" + this.id + "']")`.  Your selector may need some refining.

Comment: What does `$("label[for='" + this.id + "']")` return in the loop?

Comment: I don't know really how to do that, I'm new to javascript and I've just been trying to do this through research of other code

Comment: How about some HTML for context? Also, I would store the number more logically: as a value for the check box, a data attribute for the check box or at a last resort a hidden form field that you can access.

Comment: Ok, man, post you relevant HTML.

Comment: I need the value to stay as it is for validation

Comment: Leo it returns blank

Comment: That's the problem. Post your HTML.

Comment: ok I just posted a checkbox

Comment: Add another, from the looks of it you can just use the value of the check box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `label` doesn't have `for` attribute, that's why `$("label[for='" + this.id + "']")` returns blank, and thus `.text()` returns empty string.

You should specify it like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="enbapicks-1" name="ENBApicks[1]" value="1" checked>
<label for="enbapicks-1">1 Golden State</label>
```

If you can't change HTML, you could get the `label` from `input` with `parent()` method:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked>1 Golden State</label>

$('input').parent().text() // "1 Golden State"
```

Alternatively you could set the number as `input`'s `value` attribute, then use `val()` method to grab it from `input` elements.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="3">

$('input').val() // "3"
```

> As long as you could, always specify `for` attribute for meaningful `label` elements.

Comment: I'm not able to do that because I am using Yii2 to generate the checkboxes

Comment: Wrapping the `input` with a `label` is valid. Why not update the JavaScript. You shouldn't adjust markup to fit functionality if it can be avoided.

Comment: @JonP Yes, it's valid. OP initially tried to query with `label[for]`, so I want to give a hint on how to specify the attribute. After he stated that he couldn't change HTML, I have updated my answer for other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment. You should store the data somewhere more logical. One option would be the value for the check box the other is as a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) as demonstrated below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//Set a handler to catch clicking the check box
  $("#boxes input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    var total=0;
    //lOOP THROUGH CHECKED
    $("#boxes input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
         //Update total
          total += parseInt($(this).data("exval"),10);
    });
    $("#result").text(total);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxes">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="enbapicks-1" name="ENBApicks[1]" value="1" data-exval="1"> 1 Golden State</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="enbapicks-5" name="ENBApicks[5]" value="1" data-exval="5"> 5 Memphis</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="enbapicks-7" name="ENBApicks[7]" value="1" data-exval="7"> 7 Who Knows</label>
  </div>
<div>Result: <span id="result"></span></div>
```